# When calculating the vent size for combustion air in a confined space, do I factor in the air available from the inside space?

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, gas, natural-gas

Water heater + furnace in basement = 140,000 BTUs

Combustion air required = 7,000 cu. ft. (based on *(140,000 BTUs / 1000) x 50 cu. ft.*)

Basement = 2,800 cu. ft. so the appliances are considered to be in a "confined" space *(7,000 cu. ft. required > 2,800 cu. ft. available)* which requires a vent to outside.

The 2,800 cu ft basement covers up to 56,000 BTUs (2,800 cu. ft. / 50). So, when calculating the Net Opening Required for my vent to the outside, do you ignore the available inside air *(e.g. 140,000 BTUs / 3,000 = 46.6 sq. in. required)* or do I first subtract the area of the basement from the calculation *(e.g. (140,000 - 56,000 BTUs) / 3,000 = 28 sq. in. required)*?

Thanks!

References:

IRC G2407.5.1 (304.5.1) Indoor Combustion Air - Standard Method
IRC G2407.6.2 (304.6.2) Outdoor Combustion Air - One-permanent-opening method

Comment: ignore, since it would need to be replenished

Comment: Would not count the basement, since when that air is used, it will create negative pressure causing the house to suck in cold outside air to make up for it.